# Objective C : How to change the background color for the toolBar of MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app i have to play the video on MPMoviePlayerController.
For this i wrote the code as bellow.

```
- (void)playVideo
{
    //[imagePikerView removeFromSuperview];
    moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: self.VideoPath];
    [moviePlayerController setContentURL: url];

    int x = 50;
    int y = 50;
    int width =  CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)- 2*x;
      int height =  CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)- 50; //height = width in landscape mode
    [moviePlayerController.view setFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];


    moviePlayerController.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    //NSLog(@"[moviePlayerController.view subviews] === %@",);

    for (UIView *viw in [moviePlayerController.view subviews]) {
        NSLog(@"[moviePlayerController.view subviews] === %@",[viw subviews]); ;
    }


    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    [moviePlayerController play];


}
```

I want to change that black transparent tool bar color to redColor, (shown with the arrow)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the whole background colour you could use

```
moviePlayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

otherwise, first reset it to null

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = null;
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = null;
```

then apply the color e.g.

```
tabBarController.Appearance.barTintColor = UIColor.Red;
tabBarController.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.Red;
```

Comment: have a look at this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Listings/Classes_MoviePlayerAppDelegate_m.html

Comment: :(  hre i dont want to change color for navigationbar or tabbar,
we just want to change the colo of tool that around the progress bar

Comment: @iOSdev ah i misunderstood. just saw the arrow now

Comment: @iOSdev investigate https://github.com/lightdesign/LDProgressView or  https://github.com/Baglan/MCProgressView

Comment: u have to override the controlbar